# Path Finder: How to sort files by date, but folders by name?

Tags: macos, sorting, pathfinder

This is possible in Total Commander.
How can I make such separate sorting in Path Finder as well?

I like to sort files by date, but I don't see any point in sorting folders this way - they just jump all around when I touch a file in them (but not in sub-folder - what is the point then...).